# Mathematica failing to simplify ratio of pi-notation finite products

Tags: syntax, mathematica-online, free-wolfram-engine

I'm wondering if the following behaviour could please be explained to me:

```
In[32]:= f[n_] = Product[1 - g[x], {x, 1, n}]

Out[32]= \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(x = 1\), \(n\)]\((1 - g[x])\)\)

In[33]:= f[n]/f[n]

Out[33]= 1

In[34]:= f[n + 1]/f[n]

Out[34]= \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(x = 1\), \(1 + n\)]\((1 - 
   g[x])\)\)/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(x = 1\), \(n\)]\((1 - g[x])\)\)
```

For convenience of reading, here are the typeset versions of the mathematica output expressions.

`Out[32]`: $\prod _{x=1}^n (1-g(x))$

`Out[34]`: $\frac{\prod _{x=1}^{n+1} (1-g(x))}{\prod _{x=1}^n (1-g(x))}$

Why does Mathematica manage to successfully simplify in `In[33]` but then fails to simplify `In[34]` ? After all `f[x+1]=f[x]*(1-g[x+1])` which means `Out[34]` should simplify to `1-g[x+1]` surely?

What have I overlooked?

Comment: Just in case anyone thinks the answer is something to do with the fact that the ratio of products is undefined if `g(x)=1` somewhere -- that should also cause `In[33]` to not simplify.

Comment: You input 33 simplifies to 1, because you're dividing something by the same something, which always yields 1. However, as `g[x]` is not defined in your example, Mathematica is unable to simplify the input. If the function `g[x]` was equal to `x` for example, the input is simplified to `-n` with `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Mathematica (and human beings) need to make the exact same assumption to allow both simplifications - that the denominator does not evaluate to zero in either case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think my first comment through. When you apply `FullSimplify` with `ExcludedForms->{g[x]}` to your input 34, the output is simplified to `1 - g[x]`, which isn't the desired result. However, when a value is assigned to `n`, for example `n=10`, the result is `1 - g[11]`, which amounts to the desired result for this specific value of `n`. I assume the issue lies somewhere in assigning the value `n+1` to `x` in the result.

Comment: In general, Mathematica does not simplify expressions automatically, instead allowing the user the choice of requesting simplification or not.  Unfortunately, `Simplify` is not good at extracting terms from `Sum` and `Product`, which I view as a shortcoming.

Comment: It really just needs to recognize that it can perform an index shift to get cancellable terms. If I manage to get it to do so then I'll edit the question to include the rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Apparently, Mathematica doesn't have a rule for this case. Add one.

```
rule = (Product[expr_, {var_, 1, m_ + n_Integer}] :> 
    Product[expr, {var, 1, m}]*Product[expr, {var, m + 1, m + n}]);

f[n_] := Product[1 - g[x], {x, 1, n}]

(f[n + 1]/f[n]) /. rule

(* 1 - g[1 + n] *)
```

Comment: Accepted because this solves the immediate problem and works for `f[x+k]/f[x]` for every integer `k` that I tested. Thank you.